# How to print console.writeline() using Installer WebSetup project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

Can't able to use the function

```
AttachConsole()
    '[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool AttachConsole(uint dwProcessId);'
```

in Windows application(WebSetup Installer project) **using VisualStudio 2008**. I want to print in Console(CMD) while Installation.

When I get into a MSI Installer application AttachConsole() becomes false(Inactive). How to make it active?

We can't able to proceed further, Please post your views.

Comment: You should explain what your problem actually is. If you want to do something as the install proceeds then you can get it into the progress bar messages and also into the MSI log. You cannot attach a console because your code (custom action I assume) is running as the system account and cannot open the interactive user's console for the same reason that services running with the system account cannot be interactive.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to debug custom code in the install process, one option is to use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine().  Then monitor debug output using DebugView in the [Sysinternals Suite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx).